# Website in Django Python. My search results are not showing in the webpage

Tags: python, html, search

Here is my views.py of search:

```
def search_results(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    query = request.POST['query']
    allPosts = Post.objects.filter(name__contains=query)
    return render(request, 'search.html', {'query': query, 'allPosts':allPosts})

else:
    return render(request, 'search.html')
```

This is my search.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Search Results{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

{% if query %}
<h1>
  You Searched For {{query}}
</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>
  You Forgot to Search!.....
</h1>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

This is the form code:

```
<form method="GET" action="/search_results" class="my-2 my-lg-0 mx-3">
        
        <input class="mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="query" name="query">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
```

Now, I am getting the same issue with my logout button. It redirects me to the post.html page. I don't know where this issue is coming from exactly.
When I reload my search page it doesn't show any result of my searches.

Answer (score 0):

Form should send a POST not a GET based on your view:

```
 <form method="POST" action="/search_results" class="my-2 my-lg-0 mx-3">  
     <input class="mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" id="query" name="query">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-light my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
 </form>
```

Then show results on your html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Search Results{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

{% if query %}
<h1>
    You Searched For {{query}}
</h1>
<ul>
{% for post in allPosts %}
    <li>{‌{ post }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
{% else %}
<h1>
    You Forgot to Search!.....
</h1>
{% endif %}
```

of course post has to be parsed accordingly your purposes

Comment: "it's not working" is not a useful response. Errors? what?

Comment: same issue. results are not showing. And also the server is not throwing any error .

Comment: whenever I reload the page for any search, it takes me to the post.html page.  I think that's why results are not showing for any result. But I don't know why it's happening. My search.html endpoint is not working. Does anyone help me with this?